# Cartoon "thonk" or exaggerated suck

Tags: cartoon

Very hard one to describe or to consider creating...

Want to create that classic cartoon sound of say... A tree being sucked down into the land in a quick balloon-like slurp.

any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The human mouth is capable of more than what people like to think.

I suggest vocalizing what you're trying to do through a mic and see if that can be manipulated further with plug-ins to taste, and see if that works out.

Otherwise, reversing certain sound effects (like a balloon pop, for example), something very transient, might do the trick for you of that quick sucking sound you're looking for.

What I would do, is go to the nearest fitness center with a rubber mallet and bring a recorder with you, and record the mallet hitting one of those big exercise balls, and reverse it. This should give you that bigger, balloonish-like "thunk".

Let us know what you end up with, and welcome to SSD.

Answer (score 0):

Try experimenting with pulling a cork, or similar substitute, out of a glass bottle. Then pitch and EQ till you get something useful, and mix it in to other suggestions, such as Utopia's idea.